# Refresh a Div, Table or TR without reloading page and without using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to refresh a div, table or `<tr>`. Here no such data comes from database, its a simple error displaying block and value comes from Java-script.

Issue is that when an user inputs a value in textbox, value stored in that database and Successfully Stored Message comes on the Screen.

Then again at the same page, user try to enter wrong value then error shows in that block, but the previous value remains ie "Successfully Stored Message".

An suggestion ???

Comment: Can you give source code, which shows "Successfully Stored Message"? Or provide a sample screenshot of it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily clear an element of it's children (i.e. a success message) when some event occurs.  In your case, the event would be entering data in a textbox.  Assuming the following markup:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox"/>
<div id="message">
    Successfully Stored Message
</div>
```

When you detect another event on your textbox, you just empty the `<div id="message">` as follows:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
textbox.onchange = function(){

    // Do some test to determine if you should clear #message

    // Get your #message container and remove all its children
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    while(message.hasChildNodes()){
        message.removeChild(message.firstChild);   
    }       
};
```

Change the input's value [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Apkqr/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 3):

So after looking all over the web for this i found a simple way to do "fix":

```
             <script>
                $(document).ready(function() 
                 {
                  $("#refresh").click(function() 
                 {
                  $("#Container").load("content-that-needs-to-refresh.php");
                return false;
                });
                });
             </script>

             <div id="Container">
               <?php include('content-that-needs-to-refresh.php'); ?>
             </div>
             <a href="#" id="refresh">Refresh</a>
```

in the file: content-that-needs-to-refresh.php

You put whatever you would like to have refreshed / Updated / Changed.

Contents of file: content-that-needs-to-refresh.php

```
    <?php  
    $random = rand(1, 10); 
    $numbers[1] = "1";
    $numbers[2] = "2";
    $numbers[3] = "3";
    $numbers[4] = "4";
    $numbers[5] = "5";
    $numbers[6] = "6";
    $numbers[7] = "7";
    $numbers[8] = "8";
    $numbers[9] = "9";
    $numbers[10] = "10";    
     ?>
     <?=$numbers[$random]?>
```

This will the give you a random number each time you click on the "Refresh" link.